# iPhone - NSTimer problem when iphone locks

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I am having NSTimer that check for latest data from server every 15 seconds.
When the app goes to background, i am stopping the timer in following app delegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

When the app comes back to active, i am activating timers and it becomes active again

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

This functionality works fine.
But when I leave the iPhone, it locks after some time.
When I unlock it, the functionality is not continuing properly. Timer is not running.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't want timers to run in background. That's why before going to background, i'm disabling the timer and when comes to foreground, i want to restart timer.

Comment: Are you initiating a new network connection every fifteen seconds?  That could cause excessive network activity.  If the user is using 3GS rather than WiFi, you'll use up a significant chunk of their monthly quota.  Consider instead opening a persistent TCP connection, then have a background thread read from the connection.  It will go to sleep if there is no data, and wake up when the server sends you data.  Alternatively you can use the poll or select system calls to just check for incoming data without the use of a background thread.

Comment: Thanks Don Quixote. I'm using NSURLConnection which is persistent. So I think, this will be similar to the one that you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need an additional delegate method other than applicationWillEnterForeground.  I think that when the user unlocks their phone, your app will already be in the foreground and so will not enter it.  But I'm not sure what the delegate method will be, maybe [applicationDidBecomeActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You are right. The compliment to `applicationWillResignActive:` is `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, not `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. When the phone is unlocked and the app was in the foreground, `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how the [Apple background processing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) works...

You can create a background task which will make the NSTimer's work in the background BUT they are limited in time, you can't have it working always in the background.

Comment: I don't want timers to run in background. That's why before going to background, i'm disabling the timer and when comes to foreground, i want to restart timer.